# Change JSON structure using JS

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json in my html page with the following format

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "values": [
                [
                    894306600000,
                    1342
                ],
                [
                    894393000000,
                    749
                ]
            ],
            "key": "Beverages"
        }
    ]
}
```

i want to copy this json from one variable to another in this format

```
  [
        {
            "values": [
                [
                    894306600000,
                    1342
                ],
                [
                    894393000000,
                    749
                ]
            ],
            "key": "Beverages"
        }
    ]
```

How do i access the inner childs in this hierarchy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can access child keys with the `object.key` or the `object['key']` notation.WIth arrays, just use `array[index]`

```
var before = JSON.parse(first_JSON);
var after = before.data;
var second_JSON = JSON.stringify(after);
```